# Android in-app update - new version not detected immediately

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update

I'm trying to use the in-app update (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) to detect and install updates for my application which was published as a private app (from an EMM console).

Even if the app is visible in the Play Store the in-app update mechanism doesn't detect it immediately, but after a few hours. Is this the expected behavior?

May it be related to the fact the app is a private app?

Here's my code to check & perform the update

```
val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    //Checking the update type in IF skipped consciously
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update available, a dialog should be shown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No update available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just talked to a google consultant and got a confirmation that it is a normal situation to wait a few hours before the in-app update mechanism detects the new version in the Play Store even if the Play Store mobile app detects the new version immediately.

Answer (score 2):

well, I do observe delay with between different users when updating any app - some of them will get an update in a hour, some will get stuck with old version (no update in Play Store) for hours, even more than a day. few years ago it was even few days, also on start of pandemia... so I guess this is how it just works, such big system (distributing lot of apps worldwide) need some time to process and propagate

PS. never used this app update mechanism, just described common way